# Discrete Math Logical Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been having trouble figuring on this logical equivalent problem. Any help would be appreciated.

(p ^ q) v (~p ^ ~q) = p <-> q

My work so far:

p <-> q

=(p->q) ^ (q->p)

Using conditional equivalence

=(~p v q) ^ (~q v p)

At this point I got stuck and I don't know what to do. I assume I use demorgans law now so it would be

=(p ^ ~q) v (q v~p)

I feel that that's wrong though. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Distribution:

$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor p) \overset{Distribution}{=}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land p) \lor (q \land \neg q) \lor (q \land p) \overset{Complement}{=}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor \bot \lor \bot \lor (q \land p) \overset{Identity}{=}$$

$$(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land p) \overset{Commutation}{=}$$

$$(p \land  q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)$$

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. May I ask why distribution is the next logical step? Does it have to do with the "and" Does something signify when to do use it or one just has to think ahead of the proof? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Koreanwest Actually, that's a very good question!  Yes, I knew that Distribution would be the next logical step since you got to a $\land$ of $\lor$'s, and you needed to get to a $\lor$ of $\land$'s, and when you distribute the $\land$ over $\lor$ that's exactly what happens, as you can see in my Answer.

Comment: I think I get it now. So for the distribution law p ^ (q v r), you saw that (~p v q) was p and (~q v p) was (q v r) when plugging it in?

Comment: @Koreanwest That's one way of doing it, but note that would get you to $((\neg p \lor q) \land \neg q) \lor ((\neg p \lor q) \land p)$, and then you have to do two more Distributions where the first term becomes $(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg q)$, and the second becomes $(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land p)$.  But instead of doing this in several steps this way, I did it in 1 step, similar to the FOIL principle: $(a + b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd)$

Answer (score 0):

> =(~p v q) ^ (~q v p)

It is okay up to here.   The next step is distribution.

$=(\neg p \wedge\neg q) \vee(\neg p\wedge p)\vee( q\wedge \neg q)\vee ( q \wedge p)$

Then contradiction and identity and you are done.